# Is there a premade gesture recognizer that can be used in a native WP8 app?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, directx, gesture, gesture-recognition

I've been working on a DirectX WP8 app that needs to be able to recognize gesture like taps, pinches, and three finger pans. unfortunately, it looks like there is no prebuild gesture recognizer out there [1] (I'm hoping I'm wrong), so I made my own.

The problem is, my custom build gesture recognizer has more bugs than a bag of old flour. My application has been feature complete for a while and ironing out the bugs in my recognizer is the biggest problem keeping me from releasing.

I'm currently working on writing some good functional tests to expose as many bugs as I can, but it would be even better if there was an already made gesture recognizer out there that I could use. It's kind of surprising that there isn't since it seems like a common thing that folks would want.

Thanks for your time; I appreciate any and all leads.

-Nico

[1] However, there is one for big Windows (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.aspx) but it's not supported for Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://alysangadji.com/2013/05/18/gesture-for-windows-phone/) is a post about gesture in windows phone written by a friend of mine. He is using [windows phone toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/). Despite the blog is written in Indonesian language, there is a quick explanation poster in english about touch gesture and a downloadable sample app code. (Dont worry about the langauage, the writer did not explain much in the blog though)

Comment: Thanks for the link there, but the gesture recognizer he's using is from the toolkit (which is awesome) but resides in C# land. Piping those recognized gestures down to my C++ component would probably incur some performance issues and it appears that the gestures in the toolkit don't completely line up with what my app needs. Still good to know that there's a recognizer in the toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's anything like this.

So I'll open source my gesture recognizer once I polish it up :)

Comment: Can you please share it ?